# Is it possible to attach multiple functions in V-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, v-for

I have an array of elements, I need to render those elements in to a div and attach different on-click functions to each.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" @click="option.clickFunction">. 
      {{option}}
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      options: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "option 1",
          clickFunction: "function1",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "option 2",
          clickFunction: "function2",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: "option 3",
          clickFunction: "function3",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          text: "option 4",
          clickFunction: "function4",
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          text: "option 5",
          clickFunction: "function5",
        },
      ],
    }
  }
  methods:{
    //defining all click functions
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried the above approach but its not working, is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't working for you because each clickFunction property in each object is a string. What is the @click attribute supposed to do with a regular old string? Try

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" @click="option.clickFunction">
      <!-- I'm guessing you meant option.text here -->
      {{option.text}}
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      // pass functions around instead of strings!
      options: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "option 1",
          clickFunction: this.myUniqueClickHandler,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "option 2",
          clickFunction: this.myOtherUniqueClickHandler,
        },
        // etc.
      ],
    }
  }
  methods:{
    myUniqueClickHandler() {
      // ...
    },
    myOtherUniqueClickHandler() {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to listen for each item's onclick. So, you need to declare only one method or function for all, and pass the key value of each item as a parameter. Then, use a switch statement or if statement to detect which option is clicked.
I have changed your code as bellow:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <div v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" @click="myFunction(option.id)">. 
      {{option}}
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{

    }
  }
  methods:{
    myFunction(id) {
      switch (id) {
        case 1:
        // option 1 is clicked
        break;  
        case 2:
        // option 2 is clicked
        break;  
        case 3:
        // option 3 is clicked
        break;  
        case 4:
        // option 4 is clicked
        break;  
        default:
        break;  
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```